# Computing $f(x+\frac{d}{dx})$ operator using Taylor series

Tags: quantum-mechanics, derivatives, calculus

According to Taylor's [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), one can write $$f(x+h)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^k(x)}{k!}h^k,\tag{1}$$ where $f^k$ is the $k^{th}$ derivative of $f$ at $x$. Let us assume that the series converges for all $x$.

**Question 1:** Given $D\equiv \frac{d}{dx}$, I suspect $$f(x+D)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^k(x)}{k!}D^k,\tag{2}$$ where $D^{k}$ is applying operator $D$ $k$ times, is a valid operation. Is this correct?

**Question 2:** Assume that $f(x)=\sum_{0}^\infty a_{k}\psi_{k}(x)$, where $\psi_{k}(x)$ are  [spline wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_wavelet#Cardinal_B-splines_of_small_orders) of order $n$ (i.e., $\frac{d^{n}\psi_{k}(x)}{dx^n}=0$). Is it correct saying that $$f(x+D)=\sum_{0}^\infty a_{k}\psi_{k}(x+D)\tag{3}$$ operator has order $n$? In order words, $f(x+D)x^{n+1}=0$.

**Question 3:** Given the fact that any $f \in L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ can be represented by the wavelet series above and considering $n=3$ (Quadratic spline), is it correct stating that $f(x+D)x^N$ for $N>2$ is always zeros?

Comment: Dimensional analysis tells us this doesn't make sense if $x$ is dimensionful. But you can write (on suitable differentiability assumptions) $f(x+h)=e^{hD}f(x)$.

Comment: Related post by OP: [Exponential of an operator shifted by the derivative operator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/703491/2451)

Comment: f(x + d/dx) is not even well-defined because of ordering ambiguities

Comment: Ryan: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Hello! Please only ask one question per post – otherwise it might get closed due to lack of focus. You can always [edit] your question or [ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1: Given $D\equiv \frac{d}{dx}$, I suspect $f(x+D)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^k(x)}{k!}D^k$, where $D^{k}$ is applying operator $D$ $k$ times, is a valid operation. Is this correct?

Absolutely ***not***. In general, such a relation only holds for an operator *D* commuting with *x*, $[D,x]=0$, which your *D* is not.

Here is an obvious counterexample, for $f(x)=x^2$,
$$
(x+D)^2= D^2 + 2xD+1+ x^2\\
\neq D^2 + 2xD+  x^2,
$$
the second line being your Taylor series-inspired false identity.

The other questions are addressed, and indirectly settled  in the negative, in your [previous](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/703491/exponential-of-an-operator-shifted-by-the-derivative-opearator) question, no? Once you change the domain of your order 3 spline, you are no longer on the real line, nor is its range, and its very definition collapses into ambiguity.

Comment: I would add, to state it explicitely, that $f(x+D)$ is defined as $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(x+D)^k$, where $(x+D)^k$ is the $k$-fold product of operators.

Comment: @SolubeFish: Given that quadratic spline's derivative at zero for k>3 is zero, it means that $\psi(x+D)=\sum_{k=0}^3\frac{\psi^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(x+D)^k$?